# Align <div> boxes in a <div> to center - how come it is not working?

Tags: html, css

I'd want the logo boxes to be centered (http://prntscr.com/igwca4)
However whatever I was trying wouldn't change a thing. 
`text-align: center;` was my thought but for some reason it does absolutely nothing. Then margins to `auto`. Same.

Can you guys help me out here?

Comment: Could you post some code?  It would make your question a lot easier to answer.  From a quick inspect of the elements in question on your page, it looks like they are set to `float: left`, which would explain why text-align doesn't do anything.  Try removing the float and setting `display: inline-block`

Comment: Question cannot depend on links to external pages here. Your question needs to contain the shortest complete example that reproduces your problem, if you can't produce such an example in your question that your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.logo-item`, remove `float: left` from it and add `text-align: center` to  `.containerlogos`

(`float: left` won't be affected by `text-align: center`, however, `display: inline-block;` *will be*)

Comment: this is magic. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[flex](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)** to accomplish what you tried to do.

```
.logos-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```